# "Free for academic use" license

Tags: licensing

I am a researcher in Mathematics at a university, and I released a code toolbox that is mostly for research use, but can have applications in engineering and industry.

I would like to have a license that basically says "you can use this code freely if you are in a university and use it for publishing, studying teaching, but *not* if you are in the industry --- in that case, please reach for the wallet".

CC-NC-BY-SA would look perfect to my eyes, but using it for code is heavily discouraged, I suppose for good reasons. None of the other open source licenses seems to do what I want. Writing my own license looks like a legal mess, and I'd rather avoid it.

How would you solve this issue?

Related questions (but not the exact same thing): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232666/proper-open-source-license-to-release-academic-code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443110/practicalities-of-licensing-academic-software

Comment: https://opensource.org/faq#commercial

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax Thanks! How does this answer my question, or how is this supposed to be useful? It does not provide a solution, and note that I did not mention in my message that the license has to adhere to the OSI open source definition.

Comment: The first line rules out *all* open source licenses. It's not an answer. It's a comment.

Comment: `License :: Free For Educational Use` pypi has this option as one of its `classifiers`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that toolbox is written by your own and you want to share it with other academics. In case someone from industry is making millions you want your share (well, the sunny-day example).

I don't know any license that comes close to that.

The CC-NC-BY-SA is discouraged because of two reasons mainly:

- *CC licenses are not for software*. They know nothing about the two most prominent forms of software: Object Code (binary, compiled) and the Source Code (author version).
- *Non-Commercial*. It is undefined what this term means, especially legally.

So you use your morally and subjective day-to-day terms and every human on the planet comes pretty close in understanding what you mean, but putting this into a copyright related software license is problematic.

I'm not a lawyer, but probably some kind of passive licensing would suit your needs. There just is no license, you put your term:

> "you can use this code freely if you are in a university and use it for publishing, studying teaching, but not if you are in the industry --- in that case, please reach for the wallet

and then say this is in your own words, you decide about the meaning in case it's unclear now or in the future. (if you talk with your lawyer, a suggestion will come up that you should disclaim warranties and such which is normally suggested.)

Most academic users I bet are fine with this. Commercial users are pressured for more clarification, so you can run contracts then. Job done.

The other route would be you release under a strong copyleft license like the AGPL. This would engage user-rights (so you give a lot), however this would be the typical something-for-something, because they need to offer the software as well to all of their users under AGPL, including their changes and add-ons.

Additionally you can offer "commercial" licenses (AGPL does not forbid commercial use, however it requires to preserve the freedom of the software) as long as you're the copyright owner.

Probably either the little suspicous, "I name no license" policy, or something that's okay for you to give (strong copyleft) + X might do it. There are pros and cons for either of these two paths, so chew a bit and maybe you get a third idea that's doing it for you.

However, I am not aware of any existing license that covers your case. You might find some through research because I'm normally not interested in licenses that are for some user-groups only (e.g. only academics, only non-commercial), because the borders are not clear.